# Unir varios registros en un solo campo SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

estoy tratando de unir varios registros tipo INT en un solo campo, un ejemplo de como esta la tabla:

```
EmpresaID   recepcion
  1           4598
  1           4599
  1           4600
```

Y requiero que quede asi:

```
EmpresaID   recepcion
   1       4598,4599,4600
```

ya trate con STUFF y este es el codigo:

```
SELECT 
T2.EmpresaID, 
STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ', '+ CAST(RecepcionID AS varchar(10))
        FROM erDo_Recepciones T1
        WHERE T1.EmpresaID=T2.EmpresaID FOR xml path ('')
    ), 1, 0, ''
) AS RECEPCION

FROM erDo_Recepciones T2 
WHERE T2.RecepcionID BETWEEN 4598 AND 4600 
AND T2.EmpresaID=1 
AND T2.AlmacenID='CEDIS'
```

Pero me arroja lo siguiente:

```
EmpresaID   recepcion
   1          ,1,2,3,4,5,6,...
```

Muchas gracias y saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `STRING_AGGR()`  en reemplazo de la parte donde usas `STUFF(...)`

```
SELECT 
T2.EmpresaID, 
( SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(RecepcionID AS varchar(10)), ',') AS result
    FROM erDo_Recepciones T1
    WHERE T1.EmpresaID=T2.EmpresaID
) AS RECEPCION
FROM erDo_Recepciones T2 
WHERE T2.RecepcionID BETWEEN 4598 AND 4600 
AND T2.EmpresaID=1 
AND T2.AlmacenID='CEDIS'
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Para versiones anteriores a sql-2017 puedes user dicha construction con `STUFF()` y `SELECT`, pero el parametro de `STUFF(text,start,length,replacement)` para remover el primer character sería (notese el parametro `length`=1 y quitar el espacio en `SELECT ', '` :

```
SELECT T2.EmpresaID, STUFF(
(SELECT ','+ CAST(RecepcionID AS varchar(10))
FROM erDo_Recepciones T1
WHERE T1.EmpresaID=T2.EmpresaID FOR xml path ('')),1,1,'') AS RECEPCION
FROM erDo_Recepciones T2 WHERE T2.RecepcionID BETWEEN 4598 AND 4600 AND T2.EmpresaID=1 AND T2.AlmacenID='CEDIS'
```

Comment: `STRING_AGGR()` fue incluida en SQL Server a partir de la versión 2017 y uno de los tags hace referencia a SQL server 2016.

Comment: +1 por mi parte conocía el `STRING_AGG` pero no como hacer algo similar en versiones anteriores. Se le puede agregar un `DISTINCT` para evitar los duplicados. `SELECT DISTINCT T2.EmpresaID, ...` @jachguate, funciona bien, ya la probé

Comment: @jachguate es solo la parte que se reemplazaria de la query original, voy a agregar una aclaracion.

Comment: Hola @F.Igor, tu respuesta resolvió el problema, al ejecutar la corrección que me proporcionaste me seguía saliendo el mismo resultado, pero gracias a tu comentario me pude dar cuenta que el where que se encuentra dentro del STUFF lo estaba haciendo mal ya que al hacer esto
 `WHERE T1.EmpresaID=T2.EmpresaID` estaba recorriendo todos los datos de la tabla, lo correcto seria :
`where t1.RecepcionID=t2.RecepcionID`
Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: @jachguate creo que no me explique bien, el primer ejemplo puse solo la parte de la query que cambiaba (la llamada a `stuff()`, pero mejor puse la corrección completa) incluido el resto de la consulta (donde aparece `erDo_Recepciones T2` )

Comment: @F.Igor ahora si queda totalmente claro. Un saludo.